# How do I make rectangular image squared using OpenCV and Python?

Tags: python, opencv

I have all sorts of images of rectangular shape. I need to modify them to uniform square shape (different size ok).

For that I have to layer it on top of larger squared shape.
Background is black.

I figured it to the point when I need to layer 2 images:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
if 1:
        img = cv2.imread(in_img)
        #get size
        height, width, channels = img.shape
        print (in_img,height, width, channels)
        # Create a black image
        x = height if height > width else width
        y = height if height > width else width
        square= np.zeros((x,y,3), np.uint8)
        cv2.imshow("original", img)
        cv2.imshow("black square", square)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

How do I stack them on top of each other so original image is centered vertically and horizontally on top of black shape?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [resize image canvas to maintain square aspect ratio in Python, OpenCv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44720580/resize-image-canvas-to-maintain-square-aspect-ratio-in-python-opencv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it. You need to "broadcast into shape":

```
square[(y-height)/2:y-(y-height)/2, (x-width)/2:x-(x-width)/2] = img
```

Final draft:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
if 1:
        img = cv2.imread(in_img)
        #get size
        height, width, channels = img.shape
        print (in_img,height, width, channels)
        # Create a black image
        x = height if height > width else width
        y = height if height > width else width
        square= np.zeros((x,y,3), np.uint8)
        #
        #This does the job
        #
        square[int((y-height)/2):int(y-(y-height)/2), int((x-width)/2):int(x-(x-width)/2)] = img
        cv2.imwrite(out_img,square)
        cv2.imshow("original", img)
        cv2.imshow("black square", square)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: How to create white background? OR simply background of any other color?

Comment: @ParikshitChalke
To get any color, replace `square= np.zeros((x,y,3), np.uint8)` with:

`square= np.ones((x,y,3), np.uint8) * (B, G, R)`
Where B, G, R are the standard RGB values for colors with integers between 0 and 255.

For Grayscale images replace these lines:
 `height, width = img.shape`
        `print (in_img,height, width)`
        `square = np.ones((x,y), np.uint8) * value`
Where 'value' is the greyscale value for the background (0 for black and 255 for white)

Answer (score -5):

You can use numpy.vstack to stack your images vertically and numpy.hstack to stack your images horizontally.

Please mark answered if you this resolves your problem.