# Resize image without changing inner shape of image

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I want to resize image without loosing its original quality. for example I've 10 multiple [image: 2D images] in different size with white background. i want to make them in a same size 50*50. so that symbols should stay on same place and add extra white pixel outside.
I'm using `cv2.resize(template[1], (25, 45), 255)` but my symbol scattered. I don't want to loose quality. I also seen this post [resize image canvas to maintain square aspect ratio in Python, OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44720580/resize-image-canvas-to-maintain-square-aspect-ratio-in-python-opencv) but didn't find suitable

Answer (score 0):

here is a good reference link for this issue and using the module I am posting about.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-resize-image

but the syntax you are looking for is as follows:

```
resize_contain
```

this will resize the image so that it can fit in the specified area, keeping the ratio and without crop (same behavior as background-size: contain).

syntax example:

```
resize_contain(image, size, validate=True)
```

Resize the image so that it can fit in the specified area, keeping the ratio and without crop. It’s the same behavior as css background-size: contain property. A white a background border is created.

Resize the image to minimum so that it is contained in a 200x100 rectangle is the ratio between source and destination image.

```
from PIL import Image
from resizeimage import resizeimage

fd_img = open('test-image.jpeg', 'r')
img = Image.open(fd_img)
img = resizeimage.resize_contain(img, [200, 100])
img.save('test-image-contain.jpeg', img.format)
fd_img.close()
```

Comment: I wanna do it via python.

Comment: please allow me some time to research this issue and I will post again

Comment: if you have never used PIP, you will need to install this module for python using PIP and an easy reference for PIP usage can be found here...
https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/